# ram size of a pandas dataframe v.s. xlsx saved size

Tags: pandas, filesize

I have pandas data-frame named *df* and I got its ram size with

```
sys.getsizeof(df)
```

and it outputted 828000 bytes then I saved it to ***.xlsx*** file.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('df.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

but file-size even though its *.**xlsx*** which I supposed is bulkier (because it has excel file features) but it is not compairing to ***.csv*** and I don't know why(secondary question),anyway xlsx filesize resulted 352 KB. so why is that? why in the ram it takes more size than it's saved size(main question)? shouldn't it be vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

XLSX is a Zip file.  It is compressed.  So you can often expect it to be smaller than a comparable CSV, DataFrame, or XLS (the older format) file.